# Combine input box and select box to create a search bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have an input box that serves as a search box, and I populate a select box by querying a SQL database. For example, there are two organizations called "Dummy Organization" and "Dummy 2" in my db. So when the user starts typing "du", the select box fills with those two organizations. What I want to do is to combine these two fields: the input box (that acts as the search box) and the select box (which displays the results). My research shows that [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) can be useful, but since I'm new to js, I can't figure out how. Can someone please help me? My code is as below:

js that gets the data from the db:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchq(){
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
    $.post("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt},function(output4){
        $("#output4").html(output4);
}
</script>
```

The form:

```
<form action="newbrand.php" method="post" id="form">
        <br>
        Brand Name: <input type="text" name="bname" required /><br><br>
        Search for an Organization: <input type="text" required  name="search" onkeyup="searchq()" id="output"><br><br>         
        Selected Organization:
        <select id="output4" name="taskOption"></select>
</form>
```

The search.php file

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

if(!link){
echo "DB Connection error";
}
$output = '' ;
$output2 = '' ;
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
$searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
//$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `organisations_info` WHERE `Organisation_Name` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%' ")or die("Could not search!");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = '<option>No results!</option>';
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $orgname = $row['Organisation_Name'];
        $orgid = $row['Organisation_Id'];
        $subs = $row['Subscription_Type'];
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $orgid; ?>"><?php echo $orgname; ?></option>
    <div><?php echo $subs; ?></div>
    <?php
    } // while
} // else
} // main if
?>
```

Comment: The docs, man, [the docs](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md)

Comment: Are you saying you want a functionality like https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ or do you actually want help implementing this thing with selectize.js?

Comment: @JaredDrake, either way, I want to get this thing working.

Comment: @YohanBlake I'd suggest changing your search.php to return a json encoded array. Here's an example of a guy doing exactly what you want https://daveismyname.com/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui-bp